# Firewall redirect to translated page

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, internationalization, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony2 project with `FOSUserBundle` installed. When a user try to access http://myhost.com/forum , the system redirects him to http://myhost.com/login. 
This is my `security.yml` file:

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true

security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        form_login:
            check_path: /demo/secured/login_check
            login_path: /demo/secured/login
        logout:
            path:   /demo/secured/logout
            target: /demo/
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: /login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /forum/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Now I've regenerated the URLs to let translations following this tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/eiqd_g

And all works fine, except when I try to access to http://myhost.com/en/forum , because it redirects to http://myhost.com/login instead of http://myhost.com/en/login

What am I missing?

**Update:**

Since I added a line at `main` (login_path):

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login: 
            login_path: /%locale%/login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

it redirects to http://myhost.com/es/login instead of http://myhost.com/en/login , while other URL keep the `/en/` URL. Actually, `/es/` doesn't exist because it is the default language. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `main` firewall to the next snippet code works perfect.

```
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login: 
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        check_path: fos_user_security_check
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    logout:
        path: fos_user_security_logout
        target: fos_user_security_login
    anonymous:    true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create also a rout for the login path, something like this:

```
login_path:
    path: /{_locale}/login
```

you don't need a controller definition for it, and in your `security.yml` simply replace the the line for login_path: /demo.... to login_path: login_path

Comment: It doesn't work. But thanks to you I've moved forward. You can look at my updated question.

Comment: In any way, create a route as i wrote there, it will be easier, and maybe you need to use a listener what can take care of the locale. What happens if you simply go to the url /en/login?

Comment: If you look at the tutorial which I've followed, you'll see that I've installed a bundle which generates the routes automatically.